# <Qt5.5 Problems> QOpenGLWidget not render anything in Mac OS X

Tags: c++, opengl, qt5

Here is my problem, can anyone help me?

I'm trying to use QOpenGLWidget to render a trivial example, a triangle. But the problem is that the widget is totally black and not rendering anything.

**In main.cpp:**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);        

    QSurfaceFormat format;
    format.setProfile (QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    format.setVersion (4 , 3);
    format.setSwapBehavior (QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer);
    format.setRenderableType (QSurfaceFormat::OpenGL);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat (format);

    MyViewer.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**In MyViewer.cpp:**

```
namespace {
    static const char VertexShaderCode[] =
        "#version 410\n"
        "layout(location=0) in vec2 position;"
        "layout(location=1) in vec3 color;"
        ""
        ""
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);"
        "}\0";

    static const char FragmentShaderCode[] =
        "#version 410\n"
        ""
        "out vec4 output_color;"
        ""
        "void main()"
        "{"
        "   output_color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);"
        "}\0";

    void InstallShaders () {
        QOpenGLShader vertex_shader (QOpenGLShader::Vertex , 0);
        QOpenGLShader fragment_shader (QOpenGLShader::Fragment , 0);

        vertex_shader.compileSourceCode (::VertexShaderCode);
        fragment_shader.compileSourceCode (::FragmentShaderCode);

        assert(vertex_shader.isCompiled () and fragment_shader.isCompiled ());

        QOpenGLShaderProgram program;

        program.addShader (& vertex_shader);
        program.addShader (& fragment_shader);

        program.link ();

        assert(program.isLinked ());

        assert(program.bind ());
        // glUseProgram (program.programId ());
    }
};

...

void MyViewer::InitializeGL() {
    initializeOpenGLFunctions();
    InistallShaders();
    GLuint buffer_id;
    glGenBuffers (1 , & buffer_id);
    glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , buffer_id);

    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        +0.0f , +0.8f , // top
        +1.0f , +0.0f , +0.0f , // red
        -0.8f , -0.8f , // left
        +0.0f , +1.0f , +0.0f , // blue
        +0.8f , -0.8f , // right
        +0.0f , +0.0f , +1.0f , // green
    };

    glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , sizeof (vertices) , vertices , GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray (1);

    glVertexAttribPointer (0 , 2 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof (float) * 5 , 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer (1 , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof (float) * 5 , (char *) (sizeof (float) * 2));
}

void MyViewer::paintGL () {
    glDrawArrays (GL_TRIANGLES , 0 , 3);
}
```

But nothing is rendered and I only got a black window.

I tried to render the triangle without shaders too, and remove the

`glVertexAttribPointer(1);`

and

`glVertexAttribPointer (1 , 3 , GL_FLOAT , GL_FALSE , sizeof (float) * 5 , (char *) (sizeof (float) * 2));`

in order to render a white triangle on the black plane, but it's not working either. By the way, build and all the `assert(...)` succeeded, and I think the shader compilation worked out fine.

Comment: Mac OS only supports the core profile for OpenGL versions 3.x and higher. So you will need to make your code compliant with the core profile, which for example requires the use of VAOs (Vertex Array Objects). Also, is there no need to call `glClear()` in the paint method? Does Qt automatically take care of that?

Comment: @RetoKoradi `glClear` added and no effect either. Actually `glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);` actually gave me a red window but still no triangle rendering, I wonder if `glBufferData` actually sent the data to GPU or somehow I set the attrib pointer wrong...

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, you certainly need a VAO.